# a href enable disable from code behind asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

In my sidebar menu in a usercontrol, I want enable / disable a href from code behind depending upon user rights. I made it runat="server" and in code behind it gives me only Disabled property which also not working.

For example, refindex1 how to enable disable from code behind depending on different conditions?

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
    <div class="menu_section">
        <ul class="nav side-menu">
            <li><a href="Index.aspx" id="refindex1" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>

            <li><a><i class="fa fa-table"></i>Task Management<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">

                    <li><a href="Department.aspx">Department</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Employee.aspx">Designation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Employee.aspx">Employee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Employee.aspx">Job Master</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Employee.aspx">Job Assigning</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="frmDepartment.aspx"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>My Jobs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your C# code as well.

Comment: In code behind it shows me only Disabled so I tried with divHome.Disabled = true; and divHome.EnableTheming and divHome.EnableViewState which I guess Irrelavant.

Comment: Is your view a web form (.aspx)or MVC view (.cshtml)?

Comment: I am using VS15 asp.net project and working in user control (.ascx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li runat="server" id="divHome"><a href="Index.aspx">Home</a>
```

use `runat="server"` on `<li>` instead of `<a href>`

Comment: There is no property Enabled for divHome in code behind only showing divHome.EnableTheming and divHome.EnableViewState. So its not working.

Comment: divHome.Visible = false;

Comment: Actually, this is a menu in a sidebar so making visible false is not required.

Comment: by setting your a href to invisible, user won't be "able" to click ? just a reference for you, because i am using this method too.

Comment: Thanks Marco, I used set Visible false

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your markup looks the following way

```
<li><a id="atag" runat="server" href="Department.aspx">Department</a></li>
```

You can try to remove href for Anchor Tag following ways.

```
atag.Attributes["href"]= "#";
```

Or remove it

```
atag.Attributes.Remove("href");
```

or

```
 atag.HRef = "javascript:void(0);";
```

Comment: I tried Remove code but when I check in immediate window there are not Keys means Key Count is 0. How to set as a key.

Comment: @raja what do u actually mean by key?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code. Put some class to show the link as disabled:

```
refindex1.HRef = "javascript:void(0);";
refindex1.Attributes.Add("class","disable-link"); // or refindex1.Attributes["class"] = "disable-link";
```

Comment: Ok. but I want to make in code behind because there are some conditions to follow enable/disable

Comment: Can you use this instead:
`<li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="refindex1" Text="Home" NavigateUrl="Index.aspx"></asp:HyperLink></li>`

This way you can do:
 `refindex1.Enabled = false;`

Comment: I tried HyperLink and Linkbutton both but it effects the css and styles of sidebar. for sidebar I am using https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html Admin Template

Comment: Ohh sorry .Then the only option is manipulating `Href` and `class` in code-behind, as I've answered. Further, you can have two classes "enable-link" and "disable-link" and use it according to your condition. Also, if there's existing class you can do `refindex1.Attributes["class"] = "disable-link existing-class";`

Comment: Thanks Bikash I used now Visible = false